# issue with validating POST variable

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a `form` with multiple `inputs` with the same name. I am using js to dynamically add more.

```
<input type="text" name="links[]" id="addmore"  class="form-control url-link" placeholder="Enter full url">
```

In my **php controller** I am updating db after checking if `$_POST['links']` is set and not empty:

```
if (isset($_POST['links']) && !empty($_POST['links'])) {
                    foreach ($_POST['links'] as $value) {
                        $link = new LessonLinks;
                        $link->lesson_id = $lesson->id;
                        $link->url = $value;
                        $link->save(false);
                    }
                }
```

The problem I am facing is that even if `$_POST['links']` is empty and in the console I can see that it is, when `form` is submitted, the `foreach` code executes and I am getting blank rows in my db. What is wrong here? Not that it matters, I am using Yii.

Comment: The `links` array is not "empty". You are just submitting an empty string for each element. You could add another empty-check for each individual `$value` within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could skip the empty elements with an additional empty-check. Something like this should work:

```
if (!empty($_POST['links'])) {
  foreach ($_POST['links'] as $value) {
    if (!empty($value)) {
      $link = new LessonLinks;
      $link->lesson_id = $lesson->id;
      $link->url = $value;
      $link->save(false);
    }
  }
}
```